# Why doesn't this C++ expression generate even a warning?

Tags: c++, casting, void

I know you can supress the "expression without effect" warning casting an expression to void:

```
int main()
{
    void(2+3);
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the meaning of casting something to void is not casting the expression to an object of type `void` (`void` is a type with no objects, or better said, an empty set), but telling the compiler we want ignore the value of the expression. Other related sample:

```
int main()
{
    (void)(2+3);
}
```

there's any semantic difference between this and the other sample?

And finally:

```
int main()
{
    void();
}
```

which returns no warnings (here the Coliru [test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6725ba61cf2a2d6a), full of pedantic.related options); however, this other generates an error:

```
int main()
{
    (void)();
}

// Error:
//    main.cpp:6:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
//       (void)();
//        ^
//    main.cpp:6:9: error: expected ')' before 'void'
```

What's the meaning of the `void()` expression? Are you creating a temporary object of type `void`, which have no sense?, or are you casting an empty expression to void?

And in general, I would like to understand the complete picture about the usage of void, and which behavour/semantic is the one specified by the standard.

Comment: Note that the standard (at least, not in C, can't be certain about C++) doesn't require this diagnostic; it's simply compiler authors being helpful.  So you won't find anything in the standard that addresses this.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks. I'll update my question with your comment.

Comment: " however, this other generates an error" - there is no error in the question. If yiu mention an error, pleas also post it!

Comment: In fact, `(void)unused_arg` is a common way to switch off a warning about unused argument in a particular function if you still want such warnings to appear in other places.

Comment: For example, [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says for `-Wunused-value`: `To suppress this warning cast the unused expression to ‘void’.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `void(2+3)` is not a cast, it's a pseudo constructor. Yes, there's a semantic difference between `void(2+3)` and `(void)(2+3)`. `void(2+3)` is a construction with an implicit cast like: `void((void)(2+3))`. `void()` is also a legal pseudo construction, though with a pseudo default-constructor rather than a pseudo copy-constructor.

Yes `void()` is essentially creating a temporary with the type `void` (though as you say you can't actually have objects of void type, so you can never do anything with it; it can't be passed as a parameter, assigned to a variable, etc.)

Casts operate on expressions: `(void) (2+3)` operates on the expression `(2+3)`. But `()` is not a legal expression, so `(void)()` is not legal. Similarly you cannot do `static_cast<void>()` or `static_cast<void>(())`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk pseudo constructors support copy construction syntax. E.g. `int(1)`. Just as with regular copy constructors the compiler implicitly performs a conversion from whatever you pass to the copy constructor's parameter type. E.g. `int(10.0)` implicitly converts `10.0` from `double` to `int`. The same is true with the pseudo constructor `void(2+3)`: the compiler inserts an implicit cast to void: `void((void)(2+3))`. When you use the syntax `void()`, this does not use a pseudo copy constructor, but a pseudo default constructor, so there's no implicit cast.

Comment: @bames53 F**k voids. But yes, I've got the idea. Thanks a lot. However, I should read carefully the semantics of casting and C-like castings, and, above all, about temporaries, because the concept of "non-asignable temporaries" is a little crazy. For example, the usage of void() in some expressions like `T tmp((<some-side-effect>, void(), <tmp-value>))` for avoiding overloads of comma operator; I understand the issue, but this "non-existent object on the air" appears mystical to me.

Comment: @AndreyT True, there's a rule for that, § [stmt.return] 6.6.3/3, but the behavior is not to actually do anything with the temporary `void` non-object.

Comment: I never heard the term "pseudo constructor" before. The C++ standard calls this expression an "explicit type conversion (functional notation)", and says in [expr.type.conv]/1 "A *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression,
the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression." So it *is* a cast.

Comment: @dyp In fact, according to C++ reference (I was reading just know there), syntax T(expr) is equivalent to a C-style casting (T)(expr), which is equivalent to try a const_cast, static_cast and reinterpreter_cast in this order (if the static_cast is choosen, then a copy-constructor can be called between other possibilities). I assume then that only if there's no expression inside, a direct call to the default constructor is performed.

Comment: @Peregring-lk That sounds about right, but the last part about the default constructor is not the whole story: In the form `T()`, a prvalue is created (a "temporary", but not necessarily an object) that is *value-initialized*. Value-initialization can call a default constructor, but only in some cases. Even for class types, if the default constructor is trivial, it is not called for value-initialization.

Comment: @dyp Value-initialized, or zero-initialized? For value-initialization, you need a value, isn't? And the second thing is, which temporaries are not objects?

Comment: @Peregring-lk Value initialized. No, you don't need to pass a value for value-initialization. As dyp says, `T()` produces a prvalue, even for things like `void()`, so that's an example of a non-object 'temporary'.

Comment: @Peregring-lk "Value-initialization" is just a name ;) Zero-initialization does not call constructors, hence `T()` would not properly construct complex class types. However, value-initialization can perform zero-initialization (e.g. for fundamental types and class types with trivial default constructors).